# How to rename ogr2ogr tables on export to Spatialite?

Tags: export, spatialite, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I'm exporting data from PostGIS to Spatialite using ogr2ogr. The export is working properly, except I need to be able to rename the tables that are being exported. Here's the command I'm using:

`ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" testSQLite.sqlite -progress PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=mydb user=admin password=myPassword active_schema=my_schema schemas=my_schema tables=building_shared,alarm_shared" -lco LAUNDER=yes -dsco SPATIALITE=yes -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=yes -overwrite`

This exports a Spatialite database with two tables - **building_shared** and **alarm_shared**. I want the two tables to be named **building** and **alarm**. I tried adding the following SQL query to the end of the command, with no luck:

`-sql "SELECT * FROM building_shared AS building"`

How do I rename the tables on export?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From the ogr2ogr docs](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-nln), use the `-nln name` option to assign an alternate name to the new layer.

Comment: I believe that for being able to use -nln you must convert one table at a time. For adding new tables into an existing Spatialite database add -append parameter and remove the -dsco one.

Comment: Related to previous comment, not original question: For new tables in existing SpatiaLite DB use `-update`. Use `-append` to add rows to an existing table.

Comment: I can confirm `-nln` works well when uploading ESRI FileGeodatabase feature classes to postgres